# Not able to start Expo CLI

Tags: expo

When starting a new project from the Expo UI, I receive the following “Metro Bundler process exited with code 1”. So I ended up downloading Expo CLI 2.0 by entering “npm install -g expo-cli” in the terminal and entering “expo init” and/or “expo start” and have gotten no where. All I end up getting from the terminal is “-bash: expo: command not found”.

I also end up getting into the folder of the project by inputting “cd project-name” and again “expo init” and/or “expo start” in to the terminal. That also did not work.

I have just recently been told that my “npm” has not been installed properly because I get the error “expo: command not found”. (@notbrent) If the following is true then in what order should my “npm” been installed if mine is in this order: “…./.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js” ? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your *node.js* hasn't installed properly.

1. Go to *nodejs* website and download latest setup now probably 12 point something
2. Follow the next next string and don't forget to select check box for installation of chocolaty
3. On completion try installing expo *cli* globally  This is the finest solution and worked for everyone up till now and if not goes good with yours then your can ask me again!